# Add index to every row of a treeview

Tags: python-3.x, treeview, gtk3

This is the `treeview` I am working with, to display text from many sources (either file using open file dialog etc). It also supposed to have the capability of editing the row. (Please don't mind if the size of `bookstore /= entries`, I have cleared them for making it shorter)

```
class treeview():
    full_list = []
    booklist = []
    indxcount = 0
    bookstore = Gtk.ListStore(int, str, str, str, str, str, str, str,                            
                              str, str, str, str)
    viewstore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)
    entries = ["Type", "Id", "Title", "Author", "Journal", "Year", "Publisher",
               "Page", "Address", "Annote", "Booktitle", "Chapter"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.cell = cell.cell_renderer()
        self.view = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.bookstore)
        for i, column_title in enumerate(["Type", "Key", "Title",
                                      "Author", "Journal", "Year"]):
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            renderer.set_property("wrap-width", 300)
            if i > 3:
                renderer.set_property("wrap-width", 100)
            renderer.set_property("wrap-mode", 0)
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i+1)
            self.view.append_column(column)
            # column.clear()
            for cid in range(0, 6):
                column.set_sort_column_id(cid)

    def viewer(self, booklist, act=-1):
        for ref in booklist:
            lref = list(ref)
            treeview.indxcount += 1
            lref = list(ref)
            lref.insert(0, (treeview.indxcount))

            self.bookstore.append(lref)
            treeview().full_list.append(ref)


        self.current_filter_language = None
```

The problem is, since I am putting the row index artificially, its giving more problem then solution (e.g. if I reopen another file, `treeview.indxcount = last indxcount of previously open files + 1` ).

But since it is opening from a file, I cant get indx from `gtk_tree_selection_get_selected_rows`. So, How can I get the index?

Another potential function is possibly `GtkTreeCellDataFunc()` but I am not sure how to use, so I have not managed it.

Kindly help.

**to jcoppens's reply:** Hi, 
Putting a complete example is bit tricky as it should open a file (that will include a file open dialogue and a full window), which will probably be no more a minimal example.

But, in sort, my problem is `treeview.indxcount += 1` line. Allow me to explain the problem in more details:

Say, I read the data from a file with 6 items(so, `len(booklist)=6` ). Hence, after completing this step, `treeview.indxcount = 6`.

Now, consider, I am loading another such file, which will overwrite the existing data. But, `treeview.indxcount` will start from 7 in that case. I have tried to put `treeview.indxcount = 0` in the `FileOpenDialog`, but somehow, that is not effecting the viewer.

So, in brief, I am trying to calculate the row number in treeview while data is getting loaded.

I am not sure if this explanation is clearing the things up, or not.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I get the problem. A simple example of an operation would be useful. Did you consider using just a Python attribute?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code. Your class is called `treeview`, but it isn't a treeview. Maybe better (less confusing) if you derive it from `Gtk.Treeview` like this:

```
class treeview(Gtk.TreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(treeview, self).__init__()
        bookstore = Gtk.ListStore(int, str, str, str, str, str, str, str,                            
                                  str, str, str, str)
        self.set_model(self.bookstore)

        for i, column_title in enumerate(["Type", "Key", "Title",
                                  "Author", "Journal", "Year"]):
            renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
            renderer.set_property("wrap-width", 100 if i > 3 else 300)
            renderer.set_property("wrap-mode", 0)
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, renderer, text=i)
            self.append_column(column)
            for cid in range(0, 6):
                column.set_sort_column_id(cid)
...
```

Now, `self` actually refers to a treeview. Then, in the method `viewer` you call `textview()` recursively, creating a new instance of the class. That seems dangerous.

What is the format of `booklist`? If you pass the booklist as a sequence of sequences (eg. a tuple of tuples, or a list of lists), where each inner sequence is a line to be displayed in the TreeView, then (I think) you do not need the indexcnt.

You would have something like:

```
tv = treeview()
tv.viewer([["1984", "Asimov"], 
           ["Tcl and Tk", "Welch"], 
           ["Linear systems", "Moriarty"]])
```

This is only a partial answer - but I can't really format code in 'comments'. I'll edit it if necessary.